# Piping output of one command to the input of another in php

Tags: php, bash, process, openssl, pipe

I'm attempting to run a bash command in a php script. Unfortunately, because the command contains a pipe to another command, it doesn't seem to work as simple as writing the actual bash command into proc_open, popen, or shell_exec. I'm trying to use openssl to decrypt an encrypted password. I have the encrypted password in a database and after I retrieve it I need to echo the encrypted pw and pipe it to openssl. This is the exact command I need to run in its basic bash format:

echo $encryptedPassword | openssl enc -base64 -d -aes-256-cbc -salt -pass pass: *password* -pbkdf2

Where *password* is the password I have chosen to use as a salt to encrypt it in the beginning which I'm obviously not going to put in the forum. I've tried to use proc_open, popen, and shell_exec and none of the info I've found online seems to work. There's very little information online for chaining commands within php which leads me to believe this may not be possible and I may have to take another approach. It seems there is a php openssl plugin, however my company is trying to keep things as basic as possible without installing additional components. I also feel like this would be good information to know for other command chaining as there won't always be a plugin to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PHP has a function to do this without needing to call a shell command openssl_encrypt(). This will also be more secure due to the possibility of command injection.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and I'm looking at the built in openssl capabilities. The problem with using this is that the code that encrypts the password initially is done in swift code so it's not a matter of simply running encryption and decryption within php.

Comment: @Richard Leishman
When I encrypt it I specifically run the command echo "stringPassword" | openssl enc -base64 -e -aes-256-cbc -salt -pass pass: _password_ -pbkdf2. I need the php openssl equivalent to decrypting the encrypted password to the way it was encrypted. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @DerekDub using php to decipher an openssl encrypted string is a little complicated but possible. It should be faster than forking openssl to do the job though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the digest algorithm for openssl changed between versions. 1.0.2 and older used md5 as the digest. Anything newer than that uses sha256. Since I was encrypting with newer openssl but decrypting with an older openssl, on the decryption side with openssl I had to specify to use sha256 with the option -md sha256. Otherwise it would try to use the older md5 digest. A very helpful link that led me to this conclusion: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=225863

Answer (score 1):

With the following command:

<sub>**note:** please notice the use of `printf %s` instead of `echo` (which adds a newline at the end).</sub>

```bash
printf %s 'stringPassword' |
openssl enc -base64 -aes-256-cbc -salt -pass pass:'password' -pbkdf2
```

You get:

```
U2FsdGVkX1/PdBwO5rCJrbn5dZ5cHb9w1lH2E1LECBw=
```

For deciphering it you have to:

1. base64-decode the output of openssl.
2. Get the salt, which is bytes 9-16 of the base64-decoded string.
3. Derive a 48 bytes key using PBKDF2 with the given password, the salt and 10000 iterations of sha256 hashing (default of `openssl -pbkdf2`).
4. Get the encryption key (which is bytes 1-32) and the iv (which is bytes 33-48) from the derived key.
5. Get the ciphered text, which is bytes 17 through the end of the base64-decoded string.
6. Decrypt the ciphered text using aes-256-cbc, the encryption key and the iv.

---

Now, let's try to decipher it with `php`:

```php
function decrypt($data, $passphrase) {
    $d = unpack(
        'x8/a8salt/a*data',
        base64_decode( $data, true )
    );
    $k = unpack(
        'a32key/a16iv',
        openssl_pbkdf2( $passphrase, $d['salt'], 48, 10000, 'sha256' )
    );
    return openssl_decrypt(
        $d['data'],
        'aes-256-cbc',
        $k['key'],
        OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
        $k['iv']
    );
}

var_dump( decrypt('U2FsdGVkX1/PdBwO5rCJrbn5dZ5cHb9w1lH2E1LECBw=', 'password') );
```

```php
string(14) "stringPassword"
```

---

**ASIDE:** answering OP's initial question.

For calling the `openssl` command in a pipe inside php you can use `shell_exec`, but you **SHALL** prevent any potential code injection:

```php
$cypher = 'U2FsdGVkX1/PdBwO5rCJrbn5dZ5cHb9w1lH2E1LECBw=';
$secret = 'password';

$text = shell_exec(
    'echo ' . escapeshellarg($cypher) . ' | ' .
    'openssl enc -d -base64 -aes-256-cbc -salt -pbkdf2 -pass pass:' . escapeshellarg($secret)
);

################

var_dump($text);
```

```php
string(14) "stringPassword"
```

Comment: Wow. I don't think I've ever received such an involved and thorough answer on stack. Thank you for that first of all. So I attempted to use second method you posted with the shell_exec and for some reason that isn't actually decrypyting the pw. I'm getting nothing back in the $text var. I echo the encrypted pw from the db to make sure but it's blank after running the openssl cmd. For your first suggestion, it seems openssl is only supported in php 5.5 or later and unfortunately my establishment only has 5.4 installed for some reason. I need to have them update php to test it out.

Comment: Any idea on why the second implementation isn't working for me? I seemed to have issues with using pipes | in php when running bash commands. Swift does a similar thing where you can't simply run a long command that contains pipes. You have to create multiple processes and have the output of one cmd piped to the input pipe of another command.

Comment: @DerekDub That's weird. I tested the second solution with `PHP 5.4.16 (cli)` and it works, as long as you call the right `openssl` executable (`-pbkdf2` needs a version >= 1.1)

Comment: I made sure to run the encryption portion in the swift code exactly as you had it and made sure to use printf instead of echo. I'm assuming $cyphered, in my case, would be the encrypted string I'm pulling from the database and $password would be the password I used when I encrypted it yes? And to verify, our server is also using php 5.4.16 exactly. I'm not sure if this matters but my code is running inside an actual php script and not the php cli interactive interpreter. Not sure if that's how you were running it.

Comment: @DerekDub On the RedHat7 system where I tested PHP 5.4.16, the default `openssl` executable doesn't support `-pbkdf2`; the "correct" one is `openssl11`, so the command needs to be `openssl11 enc -d ...`.

Comment: This is where it's getting messy. So I'm encrypting it on macOS which just has openssl but it seems to support -pbkdf2 as it's not giving me any errors (in the swift code or the cli). The server running the php is in fact redhat 7 and I tried running it with openssl11 instead but still giving me a blank string back from the shell_exec. I'm not sure if using openssl on the enc side and using openssl11 on the dec side is an issue even if -pbkdf2 seems to work with openssl on macOS

Comment: Actually I will say that the pbkdf2 option isn't showing in the openssl man page so I'm not entirely sure of my previous statement that pbkdf2 is supported by openssl on the mac side. Is this option completely necessary for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @DerekDub not getting any output probably means that the command failed (you should check the logs to see what's wrong). You'll probably have to install openssl11: `sudo yum install openssl11`.

Comment: I'm just now realizing a fundamental problem with resolving the issue with openssl11 on the redhat side in that, if I'm using openssl (not openssl11) on the mac side, which we now know doesn't have support for the -pbkdf2 option, then I can't use that for the encryption part to begin with. Our redhat server does have openssl installed and removing the -pbkdf2 options from both encryption and decryption still gives me back a blank value from the shell_exec command.

Comment: I finally got this working and much thanks to your assistance. It turns out the digest algo for openssl changed between versions. 1.0.2 and older used md5 to encrypt and decrypt. Anything newer than that uses sha256. Since I was encrypting with newer openssl but decrypting with older ssl, on the decryption side I had to specify to use sha256 with the option -md sha256. Otherwise it would try to use the older md5 digest. I was able to successfully decrypt the encrypted password retrieved from the database. Thanks again for all your help!